# Using setDate for User defined class.. Java

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, clone

I have created a User defined class Date with 3 attributes, day,month,year and then i called the Date class into my Appointment class and it became private Date date.. Now i need to use setters and getters.. I know how to create setters and getters for single attributes but for a whole class like setDate, which i called into my Appointment class, i dont know how to do that.. This is what i tried to do but the values aren't changing

```
ArrayList<Appointment> ai= new ArrayList();
        Appointment ap= new Appointment(date,time);
        ap.setDoctor_id("1");
        ap.setMedication("w");
        ap.setPatient_id("3");
        ap.setProblem("pro");
        ap.setRoom("ss");
        ai.add(ap);

        Appointment o=null;
        try
        {
            //Creating a deep clone of ap and assigning it to o

            o = (Appointment) ap.clone1();
        }
        catch (CloneNotSupportedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        date.setDay(4);
        date.setMonth(9);
        date.setYear(2000);
        o.setDate(date);

        o.setRoom("pp");
        o.setProblem("Happiness");
        o.setMedication("Anti-Happiness pills");
        ai.add(o);

        Appointment t= (Appointment) o.clone1();

        date.setDay(1);
        date.setMonth(12);
        date.setYear(18);
        t.setDate(date);
        t.setRoom("p");
        t.setProblem("depressin");
        t.setMedication("Anti-depression pills");

        ai.add(t);
```

Comment: *" I know how to create setters and getters for single attributes but for a whole class like setDate, which i called into my Appointment class, i dont know how to do that"* This sentence makes no sense to me, because there is no difference for the type of variable you try to set.

Comment: @Tom Sorry what i meant was i know how to use setters and getters for Strings and Integeter only but not for user defined Date class that has 3 attributes

Comment: And this is part which makes no sense to me. There is no difference here. It's like saying I know how to sit on a chair, but don't know how to sit on a couch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you know how to use a setter for an integer, you'd do that like:

```
private int setDay(int day) {
 this.day = day
}
```

You also know how to create a new object:

```
Appointment ap= new Appointment(date,time);
```

for a constructor that probably looks like:

```
public Appointment(Date date, Time time) {
  this.date = date;
  this.time = time;
}
```

so if your date constructor looks something like:

```
public Date(int day, int month, int year) {
  this.day = day;
  this.month = month;
  this.year = year;
}
```

You can make a new date in a similar way as you made a new appointment:

```
Date newDate = new Date(day, month, year)
```

You can make a setter in the same way! It will look either like:

```
private setDate(int day, int month, int year) {
   this.date = new Date(day, month, year);
}
```

or:

```
private setDate(Date date) {
   this.date = date;
}
```

And for the above one you'd have to make the date first so you'd call it like:

```
Date newDate = new Date(day,month,year);
setDate(newDate);
```